# AudionRecorder on android

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

Please in need of your help. How do I make record, pause and suspend recording functionality on Android?

```
startRecording();
time_.setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String chronoText = time_.getText().toString();
        String array[] = chronoText.split(":");
        cmpt=cmpt+Integer.parseInt(array[1]);
        progress_.setProgress(cmpt/60);
    }
});

start_record.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stop);
time_.start();
enable=true;
```

Answer (score 0):

See official Android example here

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html